# Replace CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF in Oracle to Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

How to convert this query to its equivalent postgresql hierarchical query?
How to replace **CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF** function in postgresql?

```
SELECT emp_id,mgr_id,name,SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (name,'/') PATH ,CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF  ISLEAF   
FROM employee
START WITH  (emp_id = 345) 
CONNECT BY   NOCYCLE (PRIOR emp_id = mgr_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive queries are done using a recursive [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) in Postgres.

You can simulate Oracle's `level` by simply incrementing a value for each iteration and then comparing that in the outer query.

The leaf can be checked using a sub-query - similar to what MT0 did

The `nocycle` can be done by remembering all rows that have been processed and adding a where condition to the recursive part that stops if an employee was already processed.

By carrying the initial emp_id through all levels, you can also simulate Oracle's `connect_by_root`

```
with recursive cte (emp_id, mgr_id, name, path, level, visited, root_id) AS 
(
  select emp_id,
         mgr_id,
         name,
         '/' || name,
         1 as level, 
         array[emp_id] as visited, 
         emp_id as root_id
  from   employee e
  where  emp_id = 345
  union all
  select c.emp_id,
         c.mgr_id,
         c.name,
         concat_ws('/', p.path, c.name),
         p.level + 1, 
         p.visited || c.emp_id, 
         p.root_id
  from employee c
   join cte p on p.emp_id = c.mgr_id
  where c.emp_id <> all(p.visited)
)
SELECT e.*, 
       not exists (select * from cte p where p.mgr_id = e.emp_id) as is_leaf
FROM cte e;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/TSMVV17478

Comment: Will that get the correct leaf value when the leaves may be at different depths in different branches of the hierarchy tree?

Comment: @MT0: it can be amended to deal with that. The given example only has a single branch (due to `where  emp_id = 345` so I didn't include that)

Comment: The query is going down the management tree so it is possible that there is a branch that is `/Manager/Team Lead/Worker` and another branch `/Manager/Team Lead/Supervisor/Intern` neither the Worker or the Intern manage other employees (so would be leaves) but are at different depths (and have the same root).

Comment: @MT0: hmm, you are right. My solution doesn't cover that.

Answer (score 3):

This is the equivalent in Oracle using a Recursive Sub-Query factoring clause (a.k.a. Common Table Expression). It should map (maybe with some changes in syntax) to PostgreSQL:

```
WITH cte ( emp_id, mgr_id, name, path, leaf ) AS (
  SELECT emp_id,
         mgr_id,
         name,
         '/' || name,
         CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM employee m WHERE m.mgr_id = e.emp_id )
              THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  FROM   employee e
  WHERE  emp_id = 345
UNION ALL
  SELECT e.emp_id,
         e.mgr_id,
         e.name,
         c.path || '/' || e.name,
         CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM employee m WHERE m.mgr_id = e.emp_id )
              THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  FROM   employee e
         INNER JOIN cte c
         ON( e.mgr_id = c.emp_id )
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

*(Note: this does not account for the `NOCYCLE` clause of the hierarchical query - if this is necessary then you will need to build in a mechanism to eliminate those joins.)*